# jQuery Interface Fisheye left align issue

Tags: jquery, interface, fisheye

Using the groovy Fisheye function from the jQuery plugin Interface, and setting "halign" to "left" the effect seems to apply to the next image in the list rather than the one that the mouse is actually over.

[link](http://limitedpress.bristoldivingschool.net/css-dock.html)

Comment: Your link is broken. Have you solved this question? If so you should mark the answer as correct, or post your solution and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `margin-left: -50px;` from the style rules for `a.dock-item2` in [`style.css`](http://limitedpress.bristoldivingschool.net/style.css).

```
a.dock-item2 {
    display: block; 
    font: bold 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000; 
    bottom: 0px; 
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: -50px; /* remove this line */
}
```